# Image is not showing in html

Tags: flask

Hello I am certain that I have the image selected in the proper directory but the image isn't showing up. I did run the home.html file which the image is displaying but when I try to do the same when running through my main file the images are showing. Here is the code.

- I am using Flask as well.

'''

{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block info%}

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href = "{{url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}">

<h3 style="color:rgb(0, 0, 0);font-size:40px;" align="center">Home</h3>
<body>
    <section>
        <h2 align="center">Template 1</h2>
        <img
            src="img/Fruit1.jpg"
            alt="fruit 1"
            class="center">
        <p align="center">  This is the first template</p>
    </section>
    
</body>
```

{% endblock %}
'''

[image]

[image]

[image] - When running through main.py

[image] - When running through the HTML file

Comment: are you using flask?

Comment: Hello, Yes I am using flask this might be why it isn't showing the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I found the problem, it had nothing to do with the HTML, it was just the way Flask was set up. I had to have my folder of images in the static folder in order for it to work. I might remove this post, or keep it up if anyone else might find this useful. I will have to change this to tag to Flask instead of HTML. Everyone have a great day.

I was suppose to change the src for the image to this once my image folder was added to the static folder.

src="{{url_for('static',filename='/img/Fruit1.jpg')}}"